# How to create new arrays from object array based on user_id?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, object

I'm having trouble looping through an object array and displaying data from it under certain conditions.

I want the webpage to display the following:

```
<p>John Doe</p> <p>William Green</p> <p>Jane Smith</p>
```

I know how to do this by defining $user[0]->first_name . $user[0]->last_name specifically, but what I need is a way for the code to loop through and display the names dynamically using the user_id property as a unique identifier.

For all objects in the array with user_id 1, return "these values." For all the objects in the array with user_id 2, return "these values." And so on...looping through each unique user_id.

Here is a var_dump of the object array:

```
array(4)
{   [0]=> object(stdClass)#4336 (4)
        {
        ["umeta_id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["meta_key"]=> string(10) "first_name"
        ["meta_value"]=> string(4) "John" 
        }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#4333 (4)
        {
        ["umeta_id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["meta_key"]=> string(9) "last_name"
        ["meta_value"]=> string(3) "Doe"
        }
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#4334 (4)
        {
        ["umeta_id"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["meta_key"]=> string(10) "first_name"
        ["meta_value"]=> string(4) "Jane"
        }
    [3]=> object(stdClass)#4334 (4)
        {
        ["umeta_id"]=> string(1) "4"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["meta_key"]=> string(9) "last_name"
        ["meta_value"]=> string(5) "Smith"
        }
    [4]=> object(stdClass)#4334 (4)
        {
        ["umeta_id"]=> string(1) "5"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["meta_key"]=> string(10) "first_name"
        ["meta_value"]=> string(7) "William"
        }
    [5]=> object(stdClass)#4334 (4)
        {
        ["umeta_id"]=> string(1) "6"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["meta_key"]=> string(9) "last_name"
        ["meta_value"]=> string(5) "Green"
        }
}
```

When I output the information on the webpage, I want it to look like this:

```
<p>John Doe</p> <p>William Green</p> <p>Jane Smith</p>
```

Maybe I need to loop through objects and build new arrays based on user_ids? Please do not provide code with echo or print_r. Only "return" can be used for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate the first-name and last-name pairs :

```
$user_group = array();

ksort($user_group, SORT_NUMERIC);

foreach ($users as $key => $item) {
    $name_meta = get_object_vars($item);
    foreach ($name_meta as $meta_in => $names) {
        if ($names == 'first_name') {
            $user_group[$item->user_id]['first_name'] = $name_meta['meta_value'];
        }
        if ($names == 'last_name') {
            $user_group[$item->user_id]['last_name'] = $name_meta['meta_value'];
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
array(3) {
[1]=>
array(2) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(3) "Doe"
}
[2]=>
array(2) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "Jane"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
}
[3]=>
array(2) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(7) "William"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "Green"
}
}
```

And to print the user name pairs :

```
foreach ($user_group as $name) {
    echo "<p>" . $name['first_name'] . " " . $name['last_name'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: I replaced $users with my database query variable, and it worked perfectly. Kudos Hasta...thanks a bunch.....foreach ($users as $key => $item)

Comment: The lines with $user_group[$item->user_id] are throwing this error: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id. Anyway to improve this?

Comment: Nevermind...I figured it out. I just needed to update my SELECT statement.

Comment: I'm happy I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

So `$your_object` is already sorted by `umeta_id` and `user_id` fields?

If not, you can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function cmp1($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->umeta_id, $b->umeta_id);
}
function cmp2($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->user_id, $b->user_id);
}

usort($your_object, "cmp1");
usort($your_object, "cmp2");
```

Then simply:

```
$str = '';
for($i=0;$i<count($your_object);$i+=2){
  $str .= "<p>".$your_object[$i]->meta_value." "$your_object[$i+1]->meta_value."</p> ";
}
return $str; // this var contain all your data in string
```

Hope this helps!